# Angular 2 with Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, angular, dragula

How can I bring angular 2 into my existing symfony 2 project? so i have a subpage where i want to create a small angular 2 app. i have store all my source into my acme bundle public folder. 
My subpage is `/foo/bar` and my config looks like:

base twig template:

```
{% block javascripts %}
{{ parent() }}

<!-- 1. Load libraries -->
<!-- IE required polyfills (from CDN), in this exact order -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.35.0/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.16/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.13/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.13/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.13/angular2.dev.js"></script>

<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
<script>
    System.config({
        transpiler: 'typescript',
        typescriptOptions: {
            inlineSourceMap: true,
            emitDecoratorMetadata: true
        },
        packages: {
            'app': {
                defaultExtension: 'ts'
            }
        }
    });
    System.import({% block mainNgClass %}'/PATH/TO/MAIN.TS'{% endblock %})
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

extended twig template

```
{% block mainNgClass %} '{{ asset('bundles/acme/ListFlow/main.ts') }}' {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <list-flow>Loading...</list-flow>
{% endblock %}
```

my simple "Hello world" app works as expected:
ListFLow.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'list-flow',
    template: `<div>Hello world</div>`
})
export class ListFlow {

}
```

so here my problems:

1. there is no way for me to link html-template with relative path `templateUrl: ./../lala/doo.html` -> this is relative to my current location (`/foo/bar`) and not relative to my *.ts script?
2. i want to add third-party components like `Dragula` (https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula) -> how can i link this with composer and load into the front-end?
3. if i download the `dragula` lib and put it by my own in my public bundle folder and include it like

   ```
   import {DragulaService, Dragula} from "../../ng2-dragula/ng2-dragula";

   @Component({
       selector: 'list-flow',
       directives: [Dragula],
       viewProviders: [DragulaService],
   ```

   i get this error:

   > GET: .../foo/bar/dragula 404 not found

so all around, there are so many problems if the angular app is outside the root path, what is the best practice to handle this?